# What to do if RVA is a LiveData but multiple observers are pointing to it to call notify.....()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

So I have a LiveData RVA (Recycler View Adapter), along with an `ArrayList()`, all of which are `MutableLiveData`. However, I need to let the RVA know when the `ArrayList()`'s are updating, so I need to call `notifyItemInserted`, `notifyItemRangeDeleted`, etc. However, when I set multiple `Observer`s to observe the RVA in order to perform the following, since **they all had the same owner (a fragment)**, all the observers would be notified when **I needed only 1.**

For example, if I added 1 element to `ArrayList()` :

**Expected**: RVA calls `notifyItemInserted` through 1 observer

**What Happened** RVA calls a bunch of different methods through multiple observers

I don't think this is the right way to update a `MutableLiveData` RVA, but I don't know any other way. Unlike the `ArrayList()`, where you can just use `setValue` to update it, RVA has methods that I can't call without alerting a bunch of other methods.

One way I thought about was implementing a for loop to check what modification the `ArrayList()` was receiving and then relaying that to the RVA so it could use the correct `notify....()`. But I feel like that would be inefficient, especially since the user is updating the `ArrayList()` quite often.

Comment: Your question lacks a supporting code. Try adding some supporting code in a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) form. This helps us to understand and figure out your problem better.